# Creating a dataframe from scraping content

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would need to create a dataset that shows the list of urls and images. 
The dataset should have two columns and as many rows as the links:

```
Links Images
```

The code to scrape images from the websites is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list_images=[]

for link in list_websites:

    res=requests.get(link)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    images =bs.find_all('img')

    for image in images:
         list_images.append(image['src'])
```

To test the code, I am using the following list of websites: list_websites=`["http://news.m.istella.it/cluster?originalClust…","https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/"," https://www.playhitmusic.it/2020/03/","https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/","https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/","https://www.msn.com/it-it/video/amici/italias-...","https://www.quotidiano.net"]`

I have tried to use `df['name_col']= ...` , but it did not work (the dataframe is empty).

```
for link in list_websites:
    df['Link']=link
    res=requests.get(link)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    images =bs.find_all('img')
    df['Images']=images
    for image in images:
         list_images.append(image['src'])
```

Can you tell me what is wrong in doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append tuples containing the website link and image information to your `list_images` and then create a dataframe based on this list of values in the end.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list_images=[]

for link in list_websites:

    res=requests.get(link)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    images =bs.find_all('img')

    # if you want to have all image links in a row
    list_images.append((link, [image['src'] for image in images]))

    # of if you want to have one row per link and url
    # for image in images:
    #   list_images.append((link, image['src']))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_images, columns = ['Link', 'Images'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @lux7. May I ask if, in case of already existing dataframe (having already a Link column), it would be the same for adding only a new column 'Images'?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following: df['Images']=[image['src'] for image in images]? You would need to pass a index to imply the index row of the existing dataframe, where you want to assign a new list of values.

Comment: Thank you lux7. So in case I would need to substitute `list_images.append(...)` with a new column(`df['Images']`), wouldn't I?

Comment: let's say you have an dataframe with a column "Links", then every row has an index. Now, you would have to add a new empty column like "df['urls'] = np.nan", then use the index from the row to assign the list of images, e.g. df['urls'].iloc[0] = [image['src'] for image in images]

Answer (score -1):

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
for url in ['url', 'url2', 'url3']:
    list_img = ['img1', 'img2', 'img'] #Result of your get
    df_image = pd.DataFrame({'img': list_img})
    df_image['url'] = url
    output = output.append(df_image)
output
```

Find above the solution to your problem, you forget to init the DataFrame.